# Django dynamic page generating

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm learning Django, and doing a project for myself.

Intro about the Project : it is a travel app, where user have to select their destinations. The destinations will be added by the admin/superuser from the Admin panel.

Now I can dynamically add the Contents from the Admin panel.

What I want : when a user will click on a particular destination, this should open the destination page. as the content is coming from a Database (that means if i have 1 rows in the DB it will show 1 destination).

Now i would like to know how can I create webpages based on the contents that are available?

[Image of the code snippet of the destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9nEt.png)

in the "destinations.html", what should I add so that it will create a page when I add a new destination, as well as it will create a dynamic URL to that page.

for eg. I have 1 destination, and when I click it it will open the page of the destination (That I can do by creating a new view object). But suppose I add a new destination, and it will create a Page for that 2nd destination.

Comment: You don't need a view for each separate destination in the db. Have you done the tutorial? This is a basic thing that is well explained there.

Comment: believe it or not :D you need to create one html and one view to create multiple destinations :D

Comment: @Moha369 , suppose I have 2 destinations. how will I decide when I click on one destination it will go to the desired one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy enough, use the url tag,

i.e this is your URLconf:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.IndexView, name = 'home'),
    path('<dest_name>', views.DestinationView, name = 'destination')
]
```

your views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

# Create your views here.

def IndexView(request):
    destinations = Destinations.objects.all()
    context = {'destinations': destinations}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
def DestinationView(request, dest_name):
    destination = get_object_or_404(Destinations, name = dest_name)
    context = {'destination': destination}
    return render(request, 'destination.html', context)
```

your `index.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Home</title>

</head>

<body>
 {% for dest in destinations %}
   <a href = '{% url 'destination' dest.name %}'>{{dest.name}}</a>
   {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

the `dest.name` i added inside the url tag will replace `dest_name` and `destination` is the name i assigned in `urls.py`

Hope that solves your issue

Comment: with a little bit of modification i was able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Each of my models has a list, create/update, and delete view. Each list view has links to the create/update and delete views. These views will be used by the function within the business responsible for maintaining that data. I wanted to generate an index page providing links to some but not not all of my models. Here's how I did it.

In views.py I created a function based view.

```
def index(request):
    # this is a function based view as opposed to a class based view
    app     = request.resolver_match.app_name
    exclude = ['Process','Instance']
    models  = apps.get_app_config(app).get_models()
    names   = [name for name in [model._meta.model.__name__ for model in models] if name not in exclude]
    context = {
        "names" : names,
    }
    return render(request, app + '/index.html', context)
```

In my templates directory I created a template app/templaes/app/index.html to render the model names to urls.

```
{% for name in names %}
<li><a href="{% url request.resolver_match.app_name|add:':'|add:name|lower|add:'-review' %}">{{ name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```